# WxPython Grid Data Load Issue

Tags: python, wxpython

1. I have one program where i do load data in wxpython grid.grid say I have two column key, value
2. I have one button to trigger an event which will write data in key column
       `def load_key_data(self, event) keys_data = load_data_from_x() for row in range(0, max_row): self.grid.SetCellValue(row, KEY_COLUMN, key_data[row])`
3. there is an grid timer user to call a function whos job is to load data in value column wrt key
   `self.timer = wx.Timer(grid) grid.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.update_value_column_data, self.timer) self.timer.Start(350)  # 1000 milliseconds = 1 second`

def update_value_column_data(self, event):
for row in range(0, max_row):
current_key = self.grid.GetCellValue(row, KEY_COLUMN)
value_col_data = key_value_map_dict.get(current_key)
self.grid.SetCellValue(row, VALUE_COLUMN, str(value_col_data))`

4. Sometimes Its loading same value data for key[n] and key[n+1], its clear that it should load value[n] and value[n+1].
5. there are no logical errors in program I can confirm that, and this behaviour is intermittent

I am not sure how to use
                `self.grid.Refresh()  # Request a repaint self.grid.Update()   # Ensure pending updates are processed`

please help me to understand this.